# When are two morphisms of sheaves the same?

Tags: sheaf-theory

Suppose I have two morphism $\phi_1, \phi_2 : F \rightarrow G$, where
$F$ and $G$ are sheaves of sets on $X$.
Is it enough to show that $\phi_1(X) = \phi_2(X)$ (i.e. as maps
from $F(X)$ to $G(X)$) to show that the two morphisms between sheaves are the same?
Thanks!

Comment: You can well have $F(X)=G(X)=0$, and in that case your condition does not give much!

Comment: Thank you very much for all the helpful comments and answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, pick any non-zero $F$ with no non-zero global sections, and look at the identity map $F\to F$ and at the zero map $F\to F$.

Comment: If you add hypotheses, you'll get more lucky: flasque or soft or...

Comment: Notice that Tom's question is about sheaves of sets. But you refer to sheaves of abelian groups. (Of course this doesn't change much.)

Comment: Sheaves of abelian groups are sheaves of sets!

Comment: No, they have underlying sheaves of sets. It doesn't make sense to say that a sheaf of sets is zero or not. The term "zero" is not defined ... of course you all know this. My comment is for Tom.

Comment: A sheaf of groups is an abelian group object in the category of sheaves of sets, Martin. As I am talking to humans, the "underlying" part is essentially just noise.

Comment: I don't understand how this example solves the problem. I mean in order to show that the correct answer to Toms question is "No!" we have to find two different morphisms $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ with ${\phi_1}_X={\phi_2}_X$. In your example ${\phi_1}_X$ is the identity map and ${\phi_2}_X$ is the zero map. So we don't have ${\phi_1}_X={\phi_2}_X$. So how does it help us?

Comment: $\phi_{1,X}$ is the identity map of the zero abelian group, which happens to coincide with the zero map from the zero abelian group to itself.

Comment: Oh, I misread "with no non-zero global sections". I read "with non-zero global sections", so what you mean is only one global section.

Answer (score 1):

$F$ may have literally no global sections at all. For example, if $F$ is any connected non-trivial cover of the circle, then $F$ has no global sections but nonetheless has non-trivial automorphisms.

However, it is true that two morphisms of sheaves (on a topological space) are equal if and only if the induced morphisms of stalks are equal.

Comment: I think the last statement can be strengthened if we allow $F$ to be a presheaf: So let $X$ be a topological space, $\mathscr{F}$ a presheaf and $\mathscr{G}$ a sheaf on $X$, and $\varphi$, $\psi:\mathscr{F}\to \mathscr{G}$ two morphisms of presheaves. Then $\varphi=\psi$ if and only if $\varphi_x=\psi_x$ for all $x\in X$. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Besides, any such morphisms factor through the sheafification.